# Please expand this function.

Tags: complex-analysis

$$ g(z) = \frac{ e^{2 \pi i z}}{ (1 - e^{2 \pi i z})^2} $$
has a double pole at $ z = 0$.
So $z^2 g(z) $ is holomorphic at $ z = 0$.
So this can be expanded as a series $\Sigma a_n z^n$, which convergent absolutely and uniformly.
Thus $$a_1 = \frac{d}{dz} z^2 g(z) |_{z=0}. $$
But $ \frac{d}{dz} z^2 g(z) $ has a single pole at $z=0$.

( since
$$ \frac{d}{dz} z^2 g(z) = \frac{2ze^{2 \pi i z} (2 \pi i z e^{2 \pi i z} + (1 + \pi i z)(1 - e^{2 \pi i z}))}{(1 - e^{2 \pi i z})^3} $$)

Which is wrong?
Please help.

P.S. My text says $a_1 = 0, a_2 = -1/12.$

Comment: Why do you think that derivative has a pole at $z=0$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I've calculated it explicitly (and confirmed the result using wolfram alpha). I've edited the question, so please check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $w=2\pi i z$. Your function is then
$$\frac{e^w}{(1-e^w)^2}=\frac1{(1-e^w)(e^{-w}-1)}
=\frac{1}{2-e^w-e^{-w}}=\frac1{2-2\cosh w}
=\frac1{-w^2-w^4/12-\cdots}$$
where the series has only even powers of $w$.

Therefore
$$\frac{e^w}{(1-e^w)^2}
=-\frac1{w^2}\left(1+\frac{w^2}{12}+\cdots\right)^{-1}
=-\frac1{w^2}\left(1-\frac{w^2}{12}+b_4w^4+b_6w^6+\cdots\right)$$
for some $b_{2k}$. (In general these can be expressed
in terms of Bernoulli numbers).

Putting this back in terms of $z$ gives
$$\frac1{4\pi^2z^2}\left(1+\frac{\pi^2 z^2}{3}+16\pi^4 b_4z^2
-64\pi^6 b_6z^6+\cdots\right)$$
etc.

Comment: This would give $a_2=1/12$, whereas OP claims $a_2=-1/12$, right?

Comment: Thank you!
I've tried it, and I get $a_0 = 1, a_1 = 0, a_2 = -1/12$!